# Does this phrase makes sense? 'makes my day complete'

Tags: idioms, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

This made my day complete. I want to say that something was the highlight of my day.  Do native speakers use this phrase? is it good English? I know they use another phrase which is 'You made my day' but I'm not sure about, 'This made my day'.  This refers to something that happened during the day.

Comment: Welcome to the forum Daniel!
On this forum, it's expected that you try and figure it out yourself first before posting. I googled "This makes my day complete" and came up with many good examples of usage. If you have done this, please tell us what you found and what you're still unsure about. :)

Comment: gotube..........I googled that phrase and I wasn't sure if those phrases were correct or not.  Before asking here I always search on google.  If I still remain unsure, I post the question here to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

If someone gave me ice cream as a gesture of kindness, I might well say (as a native speaker), "That really made my day!"

EDIT:
To the original question, "This made my day complete" strikes me as a somewhat more formal way to say "That really made my day."

Comment: The question is about "this makes my day complete"

Comment: @gotube, the question also included this: " but I'm not sure about, 'This made my day'."